# Slow writing to array in C++

Tags: c++, optimization

I was just wondering if this is expected behavior in C++. The code below runs at around 0.001 ms:

```
for(int l=0;l<100000;l++){
        int total=0;
        for( int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) 
        {
            total+=i;
        }
    }
```

However if the results are written to an array, the time of execution shoots up to 15 ms:

```
int *values=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
        for(int l=0;l<100000;l++){
            int total=0;
            for( unsigned int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) 
            {
                total+=i;
            }
            values[l]=total;
        }
```

I can appreciate that writing to the array takes time but is the time proportionate?

Cheers everyone

Comment: Your question says C, but your tags say C++. Which one is it?

Comment: sorry, strictly c++ but if the int declarations were moved outside of the for loops then C

Comment: @Laurence - No, your code is perfectly standard in C99, and most C89 compilers will accept the syntax you use.

Comment: If this is C++ why aren't you using `vector`?

Comment: BTW: `int total = ((num_elements * num_elements) - num_elements) / 2;` - even faster.

Comment: In the second loop, would it make a difference when you rewrite the second loop to use an integer pointer walking along the values array, like `*(valuesptr++) = total;`

Comment: I'm seeing lots of guesses, but no examining of assembly language, and no profiling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first example can be implemented using just CPU registers. Those can be accessed billions of times per second. The second example uses so much memory that it certainly overflows L1 and possibly L2 cache (depending on CPU model). That will be slower. Still, 15 ms/100.000 writes comes out to 1.5 ns per write - 667 Mhz effectively. That's *not* slow.

Comment: +1 for pointing out cpu registers. In the second case, the code is stepping through memory, writing bytes (pulling in pages of memory, forcing caches to flush, ... then writing only a single value). In the former case, it can easily be pure L1. This response should be more upvoted.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the compiler is optimizing that loop out entirely in the first case.

The total effect of the loop is a no-op, so the compiler just removes it.

Comment: aha! I thought as much, is there a way to disable this optimization for benchmarking or is that it?

Comment: It largely depends on what compiler and IDE you're using. Check the help file/man page for what you need to do to disable optimizations.

Comment: try using total after the loop; or add -O0 if you are using gcc.

Comment: Print it out at the end, or else turn this into a function and return the value from the function

Comment: @ux9i - Printing comes with it's own performance problems, since I/O operations are horrendously slow. It's a poor way to benchmark things.

Comment: Duh, don't time the printing part. The printing part is there only to stop the optimization of the timed part, by providing a "data sink"

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple.
In first case You have just 3 variables, which can be easily stored in GPR (general purpose registers), but it doesn't mean that they are there all the time, but they are probably in L1 cache memory, which means thah they can be accessed very fast.

In second case You have more than 100k variables, and You need about 400kB to store them. That is deffinitely to much for registers and L1 cache memory. In best case it could be in L2 cache memory, but probably not all of them will be in L2. If something is not in register, L1, L2 (I assume that your processor doesn't have L3) it means that You need to search for it in RAM and it takes muuuuuch more time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that what you are seeing is an effect of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and possibly paging.  The `malloc` call is going to allocate a decent sized chunk of memory that is probably represented by a number of virtual pages.  Each page is linked into process memory separately.

You may also be measuring the cost of calling `malloc` depending on how you timed the loop.  In either case, the performance is going to be very sensitive to compiler optimization options, threading options, compiler versions, runtime versions, and just about anything else.  You cannot safely assume that the cost is linear with the size of the allocation.  The only thing that you can do is measure it and figure out how to best optimize *once it has been proven to be a problem*.